# Syntax error: Unexpected end of file reached. You have an unclosed #if

Tags: syntax-error

Below is the code used. Trying to get an image to display ony if the associated field is not empty. Thanks for any help you all can give! Message states the error is on Line 42, column 8.

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;" width="100%">
  <!-- START header -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:720px;border-top:1px solid #cccccc;border-right:1px solid #cccccc;border-left:1px solid #cccccc;" width="720">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="background:#ffffff;width:720px;height:auto; border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 27px;" valign="top" width="720">
                <font color="#222222">
                  <a href="http://www.iqair.com?utm_source=Dealer-Holiday-Closure-06282016&amp;utm_medium=Email&amp;utm_campaign=Dealer-Holiday-Closure-06282016-Email&amp;utm_content=Header"><img alt="IQAir" id="" name="" src="https://hosting.fyleio.com/40620/public/SanSerif_Desktop_01.jpg?c=1561752071758" style="border: 0px; display: block; width: 300px;" /></a>
                </font>
                <p style="line-height: 19px; margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 10px;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#666666;">Dear ${customer.firstName},&nbsp;</span></span>
                  </span><br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <span style="font-size:11.0pt"><span style="font-family:Calibri">It&#39;s our pleasure to inform you that your preliminary personalized perfect16 evaluation is almost ready. However, in order to be as accurate as possible we need the following missing information:<br />
            <br />
            <#if (transaction.custbody117)?has_content></#if><img src=${transaction.custbody135}#elseif<#if (transaction.custbody122)?has_content>img src=${transaction.custbody139}<#if (transaction.custbody118)?has_content>img src=${transaction.custbody140}<#if (transaction.custbody119)?has_content>img src=${transaction.custbody141}<#if (transaction.custbody120)?has_content>img src=${transaction.custbody142}>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="font-size:11.0pt"><span style="font-family:Calibri">You may also contact our office for assistance with the missing information so we can continue the&nbsp;analysis of the project.&nbsp;</span></span><br />
                  <br />
                  <span style="font-size:11.0pt"><span style="font-family:Calibri">&nbsp;</span></span><br />
                  <span style="font-size:11.0pt"><span style="font-family:Calibri">Please feel free to contact me if you have any questions.</span></span><br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  </span><br /> &nbsp;
                </p>

                <p style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-family: Arial, Helvetica-Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 8px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                  <font color="#222222" face="Arial, Verdana, sans-serif"><span style="font-size: 12px;"> src="https://hosting.fyleio.com/40620/public/SanSerif_Desktop_01.jpg?c=1561752071758" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px currentcolor; vertical-align: middle; width: 64px; height: 16px;" />&nbsp;</span></font>
                  <span
                    style="color:#666666;">
                    <font face="Arial, Verdana, sans-serif"><span style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-size:10px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">&nbsp;<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&copy;</span>&nbsp;2020&nbsp;IQAir North America, Inc. All
                      rights reserved.</span>
                      </span>
                      </span>
                    </font>
                    </span>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- END content -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unexpected end of file reached. You have an unclosed #if. Parse exception during merging. Line 38 column 8. Line 38 is the last line

Comment: Your table element on line 1 is missing a `<`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed closing this tag: `<span style="font-size:11.0pt"/>`